# Having trouble determining if a radio button was checked

Tags: html, css, radio-button, uikit

I'm using radio buttons in a ui-kit switcher component:

```
<ul data-uk-switcher="{connect:'#availabilityButtons', animation:'fade'}">
     <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="radio" name="perHourButton" id="perHourButton" value="{{this.spaceId}}" data-uk-tooltip title="Rent hourly">Per Hour</button>
     <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="radio" name="'perDayButton" id="perDayButton" namedata-uk-tooltip title="Rent for full days">Per Day</button>
     <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="radio" data-uk-tooltip id="perMonthButton" title="Rent for full months">Per Month</button>

</ul>
```

I want to check which radio button is checked upon form submission, so I am doing the following on the front end:

```
     if (document.getElementById('perHourButton').checked) {
                console.log("perHour Button is checked!!");
            }
            else{
                console.log("not checked!!");
            }
```

But I continue getting "not checked". I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the "radio" value is not valid for the type attribute on a button. That Might be the reason the .checked method does not return true. Try restructuring your html using input with type="checkbox" like so:

```
<ul data-uk-switcher="{connect:'#availabilityButtons', animation:'fade'}">
     <li>
        <input class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="checkbox" name="perHourButton" id="perHourButton" value="{{this.spaceId}}" data-uk-tooltip title="Rent hourly" value="Per Hour"/>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Also added an li tag around the checkbox for valid html.

If the html is generated automatically by the ui-kit (I don't know this framework), you might want to check out if you can use the javascript methods in [the documentation](http://getuikit.com/docs/switcher.html) to check which button has been clicked (using jQuery) :

```
$('[data-uk-switcher]').on('show.uk.switcher', function(event, area){
if(area == 1){ /* do something if we clicked button with index 1 */ };});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (document.getElementById('perHourButton').checked == true) {
                console.log("perHour Button is checked!!");
            }
            else{
                console.log("not checked!!");
            }
```

Comment: you have = true, but this sets it to true. Do you mean == true?

Comment: Have you tried this solution with the OPs setup? It doesn't work.